# Using the same indices between two arrays to get relevant information?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a data reader that tokenizes input strings by given delimiters. The tokens go to an ArrayList, and the delimiters go to another. For example:

```
this + is - an * input
```

This sentence would be tokenized so that "this", "is", "an" and "input" would go to the token array while "+", "-" and "*" go to the delimiters array. Now, I need to store the original indices of these as well, so that the tokens would have indices 0, 2, 4 and 6 and the deliminators would have indices 1, 3 and 5. The normal solution would be to put them into the same array, but I need to keep them separated for performance reasons (e.g. to quickly check through the delimiters).

How could this indexing be done so that when I have a token index 'i', I could easily get the deliminator from index 'i+1' without looping through all the delimiters?

Comment: Are the delimitors unique? Or are you storing duplicates?

Comment: Can you have multiple tokens between delimitors?  What constitutes a delimitor?

Comment: Delimiters are not unique, and I need to store duplicates. There may be multiple tokens between delimiters. There's a list of about 20-30 different delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), having the index as key and the delimiter as value. It even has the method `containsValue()` which I think might be useful for you.

Comment: How would that happen in practice?

Answer (score 0):

Tried posting this as a comment to @Pescis answer but couldn't format it well.

```
public class Split {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String in = "this + is - an * input";

        StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(in, "+-*", true);
        Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();

        int x = stringTokenizer.countTokens();

        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            map.put(i, stringTokenizer.nextToken());
        }

        System.out.println(map);
        System.out.println(map.get(0));
        System.out.println(map.get(1));
    }
}
```

Output

```
{0=this , 1=+, 2= is , 3=-, 4= an , 5=*, 6= input}
this 
+
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the questions. In your code, the tokens and delimiters are in the same storage. I need them in separate arrays (or other structures) so I can iterate through them separately, but I also need to access both of them with the original indices.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment to my other answer

```
import com.google.common.collect.Table;
import com.google.common.collect.TreeBasedTable;
public static void main(String[] args) {
            String in = "this + is - an * input";
            Table<Integer, String, String> table = TreeBasedTable.create();
            StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(in, "+-*", true);

            int x = stringTokenizer.countTokens();

            for (int i = 0; i < x / 2; i++) {
                table.put(i, stringTokenizer.nextToken(),
                        stringTokenizer.nextToken());

            }
            if (stringTokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
                table.put(x, stringTokenizer.nextToken(), "");
            }

            // iterate through tokens
            System.out.println(table.columnKeySet());
            // iterate thruogh delims
            System.out.println(table.values());
        }
```

with the following outputs

```
[ an ,  input,  is , this ]
[+, -, *, ]
```

Comment: I think this still doesn't answer to my original question. For example, if I have a token at index i, I can't get the following delimiter from index i+1.